# How to use EntityListeners with flyway migration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway, entitylisteners

Simply I need an answer for why it is not working and find an alternative if this is not possible.

I am using entity listeners annotation, which helps me catch events around changes with my database tables where I trigger my "business things".

Code example:

```
@EntityListeners(MyClassEntityListener.class)
@Entity
public final class EntityClass {
  //... attribs. here
}

public class MyClassEntityListener {
  @PostUpdate
  @PostPersist
  void onUpdate(EntityClass entityClass) {
    // ... business here -> this is not called with flyway migrations
  }
}
```

Flyway migration example:

```
insert into entity_class (uuid, ...) values
('c8297c38-04e4-48ed-afb6-070c8d994d54', ...);
```

Everything works fine, if I create/update entities through controllers with API as hibernate and transactions are used there. With flyway migration, this is not working - a row is created and the listener is not called. The simple question is why and how to make a workaround.

I do not want to use flyway callbacks, because one migration file can contain many new entities and I need to call my onchange/onupdate callback for every entity.

I am using mysql as database and flyway version `8.5.0`, springboot version `2.7.3` and `java 17`.

Answer (score 1):

JPA will manage your `EntityListeners`. The flyway migration SQL script will use a database connection and send SQL to the database, which JPA will not be aware of. You may want to have a look at the [Flyway migration documentation](https://documentation.red-gate.com/flyway/flyway-cli-and-api/concepts/migrations) on the section of "Java-based migration", in which you can assemble the relevant part of your application for the entity listeners to work, and then use JPA to manipulate your database content. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for pointing to this feature, but my bad, I forgot to mention, that I already have hundreds of migration files not applied in production yet and this way seems to be quite difficult for me to rewrite all migration files to Java classes and I cannot afford this solution, I need to find something more simple and less time consuming without creating spaghetti code, but I believe your answer will help many others